# Как правильно в MongoDB обновлять массив или сложный атрибут?

Tags: mongodb

У меня есть коллекция документов с большим массивом.

Как правильно, например, удалить несколько элементов массива, изменить порядок (отсортировать) или добавить в конец новый элемент? 
Нужно перезаливать массив ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте операции для работы с массивами. С помощью них можно модифицировать массив различными образами.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/

Если массив настолько большой, что операции поиска элемента занимают длительное время, то можно сделать индекс на массив.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/